# What is the difference in using mozilla to acess a web service or using the installed service's app?

Tags: firefox, websites

Everytime I enter facebook or youtube, for exemple, they ask if I wanna install the app. Is there any bonus doing so? It's mobile like where the apps fry your battery doing background things? Is it faster ou anything more? For fans: I'm not asking which is better, only the differences.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** What version of Ubuntu are you using on which hardware?

Comment: "apps fry your battery doing background things?" Not probably the topic here but whoever told you that doesn't understand how programs in RAM work.

Comment: Android facebook app consumes a lot a battery updating all sort of things like notifications and events. I just wanna know if in Ubuntu is the same thing. I'm using 14.04 at a 8gb ram, i5, dell inspiron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the install will not install a regular app. What it installs is known as a web app.

This will cause it to still open up in your browser, but it will be able to do some 'smart' interactions with Ubuntu (like using Ubuntu's notification for notification, dash integration, volume panel integration etc.) and a shortcut will be added to the dash in most cases.

So the difference is just that the website/app is smart in being able to appear as a local app while still running in the browser.